# How to represent boolean expressions using if/else statement(s)? Is this right?

Tags: java, boolean-operations

Is the expressions

```
!(a ==b)    a!=b equivalent?
```

i have yes here

```
!a && b     b &&!a
```

yes

```
!a || b     b ||!a
```

no

And how to write an if/else statement that stimulates the following expression:

```
z=(100>y) ? z*2 : z/2;
```

if (100>y)

```
z=z*2;
```

else

```
z-z/2;
```

what is z= and y= in the end?

i have z=40 and y=12

How to expand the expression `y+=2`

```
y=10, z=20
```

Comment: There are no `%%` and `//` operators. Do you mean `&&` and `||`?

Comment: Hi Margarita! Welcome to StackOverflow. I first want to ask - what work have you done on this problem? It's great you have found this site to ask questions, but you're not likely to get free answers unless you've tried to work out the problem yourself. We're not doing it to be mean - just want you to learn. If you post up a solution that you've tried, you are much more likely to get pointers sending you in the right direction. I hope that helps, and welcome again to StackOverflow!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant that! Yes it is, but I have no idea how to do that, because my major is Psychology, but I have to do that=((

Comment: @Margarita, the fact that your major is Psychology, does not mean you can cheat. I imagine that even for Psychology you need to be able to do a bit  logical reasoning :). Just read it out loud to yourself and replace the operators by words, making: `!(a ==b)` and `a!=b`: `NOT(a equals b)` and `a IS NOT b`.

Comment: Thank you=) I know, it is just the beginning of class, I'm totally lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int y = 10;
    int z = 12;     

    System.out.println(!(a ==b));
    System.out.println(a!=b);

    if (100 > y) z = z*2; else z = z/2;
    System.out.println(z); 
    System.out.println(y);

    y = y + 2;

    System.out.println(y);

}
```

**Output**:

The value for !(a ==b) is: true

The value for (a!=b)) is:true

24

10

12

**Additional:**
Some times **(?:)** conditional operator is a bit tricky this means that it takes three operands. Together, the operands and the ?: symbol form a conditional expression. The first operand (to the left of the ?) is a boolean expression (i.e., a condition that evaluates to a boolean valuetrue or false), the second operand (between the ? and :) is the value of the conditional expression if the boolean expression is True and the third operand (to the right of the :) is the value of the conditional expression if the boolean expression evaluates to false. For example, the statement:

```
System.out.println( studentGrade >= 60 ? "Passed" : "Failed" );
```

Comment: You could alternate `a` between `true` and `false`, and same with `b`.  Then spit out all combinations for each expression and demonstrate the equivalence or lack thereof through a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is an instance of de Morgan's Laws which you would do well to look up.

Comment: Thanks. Formal Logic 101 is a long time ago :-|